# NextJS getInitialProps returning 404 rather than redirecting with res.writeHead(302)

Tags: next.js

I am returning the following in `pages/_error.js`

```
Page.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
   ...
   ctx.res.writeHead(302, { Location: "https://test.com/my-redirect-url-here" }).end();
   return {}
}
```

Looking at the http response headers, I see:

```
location: https://test.com/my-redirect-url-here
```

However, a 404 is rendered (and the above response code is 404, not 302 that I would expect). Why would it be returning a 404?

Note: I also tried using `getServerSideProps` but am getting https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/gssp-export when building for deployment (even though I'm not using `next export` in my build command). (Update: I think this is because it is enforced in Vercel)